# Display WordPress archive template page in 3 columns and not 1 column

Tags: php, templates, archives

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

Currently WordPress display them in 1 column:

[image]

Is there code I can Add to the template file, to display all the blog post in this grid layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the structure, class names, ids etc. it would be impossible to give you an answer that would help.

But lets say that the structure is ul>li*6

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

The must basic of css that would create such a design would be

```
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px 50px;
}
```

You would need to adjust the gap im sure, but this is a good starting point

> EDIT

Ok so following your answer with the image the css target would be `.page-content`, but that could target other elements with the same class.

Try looking for a parent with a unique class or id that you can use to make sure your css only target that specific element

Comment: Please comment below

Comment: Wonderful it works!! thanks a million